Why does calling setuid() return "Bad system call"?
So actually, I have Android 13.
The problem is in my C code (probably?).
When I call setuid(0) or setuid(getuid()) in my phone, I get this output:
Bad system call

Meanwhile on my laptop with Ubuntu, setuid() doesn't throw any error, and returns -1 (so that's how it should be).
Then why does Android's setuid() throw that?
And if Bad system call is normal for Android, then how can the Android system call setuid() for each Java application (uid 10000 and greater)?

Android blocks "unused" syscalls using seccomp filter: "the system crashes an app that uses an illegal syscall".

Android blocks some system calls from being called by apps. This is implemented by the seccomp filter from Android 8 onwards. This deliberately crashes apps that try to call blocked system calls and that's what you're hitting.
Android uses Linux uids for individual apps, rather than different users. Each app has an individual uid from all of the other apps on a device. The uids apps run under have names like u0_a40 or u0_a121, rather than being defined by the app. They seem to be picked at installation time, rather than being chosen by the app developer.
There are also a number of special uids that are built into Android, such as the shell uid that adb shell sessions run under, system and wifi. Customised versions of Android have other named uids like vendor_samsungcloud which I can see on my Android 14 Samsung 'phone. To explore this a bit more:
L$ adb shell               # At the Linux shell prompt
A$ ps -A | more            # At the Android shell prompt

You'll find that there are a few cases of multiple processes running under the same u0_aXYZ uid, but the names of the processes seem to indicate that they're part of the same app.
Giving apps individual uids provides a simple way to make their data private from each other. Their files are owned by their uids, so if they have -rw------- permissions, they're only accessible to the app.
ART (Android Run Time), which hosts apps, presumably has a way to change the uid of an app, likely by bypassing the seccomp filter to allow it to call setuid().
Android uses a Linux kernel, but it is not a conventional Linux operating system. Trying to treat it as such is an exercise in frustration. Trying to find a way to call setuid() yourself is malware-like behaviour. You need to learn the Android way of doing things.
Android is far more locked-down than Ubuntu because it's designed to be hard to mess up by people who think they understand computers, but are utterly wrong about that. An example of that level of stupidity that a friend had to deal with in the 1990s: a Windows 95 user who decided to delete all the files he didn't recognise from his c:\windows directory, and when his computer stopped working, rang his ISP to complain about malware attacking him.

Android uses Linux uids for individual apps, rather than different users - Sorry, can you explain this? Uses Android setuid() or another method to change uid 0 to (for example) uid 10076?

@BHmsgameJava: revised.

now I understood. Thanks!
